# ZAP PROXY : security testing for REST API

Tags: web-services, rest, security-testing

Any help here will be greately appreciated :)
Wanted to check if anyone has used [ZAPProxy](http://code.google.com/p/zaproxy/) for performing the security testing on the RESTfull WebServices (API). I know this tool provides good out of the box features  for doing security testing on WebSites but I'm not sure how effective it on on the WebServices. I know I can use SOAPUI but I have heard that is not comprehensive. 
Please suggest !

Answer (score 0):

I use it for making SQL-Injection attack tests.
Great tool!
Receive the manual browsing data of your intercepting proxy via REST Webservices, process the the data, resend malicious web request, evaluate response and if you're not sure in your program if the response is right display it in an eclipse RCP webbrowser.